# how to update same fields but different tables in php codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to update two fields in table. But they are in two different tables. I want to update them simultaneoulsy  in php codeIgniter.

Comment: Sounds like two update statements wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: What do you need help with?  Do you just not know how to do this?  Or do you have something that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want update two columns in two different table use following query.

```
$query="UPDATE table1,table2  SET table1.status=value , table2.status=value";
$this->db->query($query);
$this->db->update('table1');

if($this->db->affected_rows()=='2')
{
    return TRUE;
}
```